# The author's name is written "Unknown" in blogger widgets, what can I Do?

Tags: templates, blogger

I have Jannify template in Blogger, but in the widgets, the author's name is written "Unknown". How can I write the author's name correctly or delete the author name?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTdii.jpg)

Comment: Please, provide more information like what widgets, are they from blogger or a third-party? Also, some code from the issue would be helpful. Otherwise, I don't think you will get much help here. Most people don't even reply to questions with only an image attached.

Comment: thank you. Unfortunately, I am not very familiar with coding and website design. The template I use is Jannify and it is on this website:
https://jannify-templateify.blogspot.com
On the main page, all the big pictures that should have the author's name are written Unknown, But when we click on the post, the author's name is written correctly on the post page.

Answer (score 0):

Go to setting in blogger, then go to last option = user profile, then tick the box next to share my profile, and save the changes by scrolling down.